# Can't understand why the for loop doesn't work

Tags: python

I try to do a hangman game, but i don't know why the for loop doesn't work, this is the code:

```py
import numpy as np

parole = np.array(["anatra","alfabeto","computer","tastiera","monitor","melanzana","quaderno","macchina","cielo","parola","numero","telecamera","moto","guanti","casco","palestra","bilancere","pasta","pentola","padella"])

Word = np.random.choice(parole)

Try = []
Length = ""
for i in Word:
    Length += ""

print(Word)
while Try != Word:
    print(Try)
    prova = input("Inserisci lettera: ")
    for i in range(len(Word)):
        if prova in Word:
            temp = ""
            temp[i] = Word[i]
            Try.append(temp)
        else:
            prova = input("Sbagliato, riprova: ")

print(Word)
print(str(Try))
```

and this is the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Gemxs\Documents\Python\Numpy\pratica numpy.py", line 19, in <module>
    temp[i] = Word[i]
    ~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: The error tells you why: you can't assign a new value to a character in a string by index. Perhaps you meant to do `temp += Word[i]` instead of `temp[i] = Word[i]`?

Comment: There's no need to tag VSCode. It's an issue with your code. You can read this again `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Why are you using numpy? What are you hoping the *for* loop will achieve?

Comment: What is `Length` for; you never use it. I am not clear on what you are trying to do. But you can convert a string to a List (say `my_list`) and then access/change characters using an index and then convert back to a string using `"".join(my_list)`

Comment: that is a skill called debugging, you should learn it and not depend on others to write your code

Comment: This isn't a problem with the loop; `str` values are immutable, so you can't assign to a specific index in a `str` value (even if `temp[i]` would be an otherwise valid reference to a specific character, which likely isn't here because you just assigned the empty string to `temp`.)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry - I'm not able to comment yet so have to type in the answer section. I think you're probably ending up in an infinite loop as you're asking the while loop to run until the string (word) is exactly equal to the list (try) which it's never going to be as they're two different types.

Also try actually does something in Python so it might be better to use "current_guess" or something like that and initiatilise it as a string of underscore characters that match the length of the word

```
current_guess = "_" * len(Word)
```

Since we're now dealing with strings rather than lists, you're going to need to change from apend to simply updating the string with the new and old guesses

```
# Game loop
while current_guess != word:
    # Ask the player to guess a letter
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

    # Check if the guessed letter is in the word
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == guess:
            # Replace the underscore with the correct letter
            current_guess = current_guess[:i] + guess + current_guess[i + 1:]
```

A few more tweaks to get it the way you want it and I think that should work for you.

Comment: Oh now I understand where i was wrong. Thank you!